# How to get saved text layout from database

Tags: sql, css, database

When I add text to my mysql database using a textarea the format of the text is somehow saved (newlines and spaces) this layout isn't shown in the database itself as far as I know. When i load this string from the database into the a textarea again I get the same format as I inserted. But when I try loading this string into a div it will just show up as one line.

So my question is: How do I set the formatted text in a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `<div>` to use the same white-space as `<textarea>` and `<pre>` uses.

```css
div{
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the nl2br function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 0):

what language are you using to get your data to web page?  php?

if so `htmlentities($mystring)` will convert line feeds to `<br>` etc.

You can also put

```
<pre>
your text
</pre>
```

which will show it a little like plain source code.

Answer (score 0):

there a two ways to do this:

first way is to use the php function [nl2br()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to setup \n in < br >, the second way is to give your div a class an format it by [CSS white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)